# Which SC2 units can accidentally cause friendly fire?

Tags: starcraft-2

Which units in Starcraft 2 cause friendly fire?

I already know that Siege Tanks do, as can misplaced Psionic Storms, but I was surprised to learn that Colossi and Banelings do **not**.

Which units can accidentally inflict damage on your own forces?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only units that *actually* cause  friendly fire from splash damage are:

- Siege tank shells
- Psionic storms
- Widow Mine attacks (except for other widow mines)
- Raven's Seeker Missiles
- Ghost's EMP
- Ghost's Tactical Nuke

Some units that you *might* expect to cause FF splash damage but in fact **don't** are:

- Yamato cannon on BCs *(doesn't cause any splash)*
- Planetary Fortresses
- Hellion/Hellbat attacks
- Thor attacks
- Baneling explosions
- Infestor's fungal growth
- Ultralisk attacks
- Mutalisk attacks
- Colossi attacks
- Archon attacks

**Edit:** See [this website](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Splash_damage) for more details.

Comment: Mutalisks should not be expected to friendly fire, 'cause everyone knows glave wurms are intelligent, cunning and compassionate! :)

Comment: @OrcJMR: For certain definitions of "compassionate".

Comment: Yamato Cannon does not cause any splash damage. Otherwise a great list.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I worded the second list's title wrong. The Yamato cannon is basically a mini-nuclear explosion, and the animation for it might make people think it does splash so that's why I included it. I edited the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently the units which can cause friendly fire are Siege Tanks (in siege mode), Psionic Storms, Widow Mines, and Raven's Seeker Missiles.

Comment: You missed Ghost's EMP & Tactical Nuke. Although in most situations a player would have to either be an idiot or intend to EMP or Nuke themselves, it does happen accidentally. There's a common terran technique where the T will drop a nuke force an enemy retreat &  gain a better position, then cancel it before it lands.

I can't remember who did it, but I do remember in an SC2 WoL pro game TvP where the terran dropped a nuke to gain a positional advantage, then forgot to cancel and walked his army right underneath it.